# Where can we find the Spartacus OOTB Component HTML's

Tags: spartacus-storefront

For the available existing OOTB Spartacus Component's in Cart, PLP, PDP or Checkout pages, where we can get see the list component HTML's and Stylings used.?

Answer (score 2):

Let's use one example for illustration. Say if you want to explore the html implementation of component named "UnitDetailsComponent", just search it in github repository: https://github.com/SAP/spartacus/search?q=UnitDetailsComponent

Then you can find its path in project: feature-libs\organization\administration\components\unit\details\unit-details.component.ts

[image]

With this path you can find its html implementation: feature-libs\organization\administration\components\unit\details\unit-details.component.html

[image]

Best regards,
Jerry

Answer (score 0):

We used to have a documentation link but since a week it giving 404([link](https://sap.github.io/spartacus/index.html)).

The Spartacus repo is public so you can clone and see components and styles there - [repo](https://github.com/SAP/spartacus).

You can see the documentation to see how to override components and also to customise OOTB components - [docs](https://sap.github.io/spartacus-docs/customizing-and-extending/).

Comment: https://sap.github.io/spartacus-docs/ this is the new link

Comment: Hi @ErikSlagter, the Spartacus docs link always worked. Its the other documentation link which has stopped working since last few days. It was quite handy to look into documentation of the component. it had a search box and if we say searched for UpdateProfileComponent, we could see the ts and html content right there along with hierarchy, etc.

Comment: ah that one, not sure what happened with that. I just have VS code open with the source code of the spartacus library in the version that i am working on. Works better imho